# Jinja2 and WTForms nesting

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, jinja2, wtforms

I'm using the following code at the moment to generate a label:

```
{{ form.code.label(class="control-label required") }}
```

Note the required class. 
This is now hardcoded but I want to add that dynamically based on WTForms field info:

```
form.code.flags.required
```

I tried something like

```
{{ form.code.label(class="control-label {% if form.code.flags.required 
%}required{% endif %}") }}
```

but it didn't worked. 
Is there way some solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This example wouldn't work because Jinja2 doesn't treat the syntax inside the '{{}}' brackets as part of the template, although it tries some smart parsing to try to figure out what you want (more info here: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#variables).

The simplest method would be to move the logic outside:

```
{% if form.code.flags.required %}
    {{ form.code.label(class="control-label required") }}
{% else %}
    {{ form.code.label(class="control-label") }}
{% endif %}
```